# aws command works in WSL, but not as one-liner from PowerShell

Tags: command-line, amazon-web-services, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) on windows 10, and installed the Amazon AWS cli on it. When I start WSL (`C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe` in PowerShell) and then `aws` it works fine. If I try to run it as a one-liner (`C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe aws`) it doesn't find the `aws` command. I need it as a one-liner to be able to use it from a VS Code task.

```
PS C:\Users\pablo.DCA> C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe aws
/bin/bash: aws: command not found
PS C:\Users\pablo.DCA> C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe
pablo@DCA-WS01:/mnt/c/Users/pablo.DCA$ aws
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: too few arguments
```

A simple `echo` command does work:

```
PS C:\Users\pablo.DCA> C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe echo Hi
Hi
```

And so does Python (which I used to install aws):

```
PS C:\Users\pablo.DCA> C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe python
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Why does this happen? And how can I fix it, or what could I try to figure out what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely AWS is not in a system path, like `/usr/bin/`. If you are adding it to your `$PATH`, e.g. in `~/.bashrc`, it normally won't be executed unless you restart your terminal.

One option would be to use the full path to aws in your one line call from Windows:

```
c:\\windows\\system32\\wsl.exe /home/username/.local/bin/aws
```

Or you could force bash to behave as if it was invoked as a login shell with the `-l` (or `--login`) option

```
 c:\\windows\\system32\\wsl.exe bash -l aws
```